# log4net - How do I write the Server's IP address to the log

Tags: log4net, ip-address

Is it possible to write the Server's IP address to the log?
I am using ASP.net 4, MVC3, WinServer2008 R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the in-built [HostName Property](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.SystemInfo.HostName.html)

`<conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}"/>`